# startActivity + .class constructions

Tags: android

Is it possible to pass TargetActivity.class to another activity and do something like:

```
// first activity 
intent.putExtra("target", TargetActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);

//second activity
startActivity(this, getIntent().getExtra(/*target*/);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

**// first activity**

```
intent.putExtra("target", "YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME.TargetActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

**//second activity**

```
    String className=getIntent().getStringExtra("target");
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    try {
        intent.setClass(CurrentActivity.this, Class.forName(className));
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**EDIT:**

Answer (score 1):

you can pass as string in intnet and can use Class.ForName............

```
 Class t = Class.forName("java.lang.Thread")
```